# Noahide reading Psalms

Tags: torah-reading, tehilim-psalms, noachide-laws, noahidism, noahide

Can Noahides read Psalms? I've been told that some can't be read by non-Jews. If so, which ones? I don't want to end up reading it if it wasn't meant for me to read.

Comment: Do you have a rabbi to guide you on questions like this one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that some parts that refer to our Hashem the Hashem of our forefathers and the like, are not fitting for Noahides to say. Certainly not as a prayer because it has no meaning. I also once heard there is a difference of opinion whether reciting Tehillim is Prayer or Learning. Most say it counts as learning and thus even if you  don't understand every word or meaning you still get reward for learning. Prayer implies understanding the prayer. Others disagree and say the words themselves have the power of prayer and when coupled with your thinking you can achieve your heart's desire.
Personally, I think that if the power of the words being recited is what is effective, then even if the meaning has no bearing on the Noahide, but his/her recitation is sincere in seeking to create Holiness, praise Hashem, bring his soul closer to Hashem, etc., then I don't see why he cannot recite in sincerity and with focus on bringing Holiness to this mundane plane.
If cites are needed, I can find them.